# Duplicate value in 2D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, xcode6

I am trying to fill 2D array via loops. but it duplicates the last value as shown below.

```
1 2 3 
3 4 5 
5 6 7
```

Code:

```
void fillArray(int array[][2])
{
int val = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 3;++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
    {
        array[i][j] = ++val;
    }
    --val;
}
}
```

Any solution to this?

Comment: lol, remove `--val;` ...

Comment: Beat me to it and you added an extra lol. Not quite a typo, but voting to close as off topic, unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: Likely, undefined behavior  `array[][2]`  (not 3)

Comment: Your row stride is claimed by your parameter as `2`, but your code uses a `3` element stride. I'd fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have `--val;` which reduces the number at the end of each row. Remove this to get sequential numbers.

Comment: The reason I have --val, because if I don't add this, the result is as below:
`1 2 4` and so the 3rd digits is digit+2, in every row.

Update: fixed it by removing --val, and adding 3.